# SQL Server : convert Geometry to Geography

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial

I have been having some trouble converting polygons from `Geometry` to `Geography`.

I have found the following articles and have taken the steps advised but I am still unable to convert all the instances to valid `geography` objects.

Union start point to ensure correct orientation
blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b.aspx

Reduce polygon
blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2009/06/05/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-2.aspx

Buffer and negative buffer
http://www.beginningspatial.com/fixing_invalid_geography_data

Remove points from collection after reduce
http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/cleaning-up-artefacts-created-by-reduce/

My process thus far is the following.

Import shape file to SQL Server Developer Edition (64-bit) using Morten Nielsen's excellent Shape2Sql tool from `www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools.aspx`

I had to import the shape file as `geometry` as I was getting errors about invalid `geography` values.

Then I tried to create `geography`'s as per my SQL script below.

```
drop table [MapData].[dbo].[World_SeasSplitGeog]

SELECT 
  [IDX]
  ,[OBJECTID]
  ,[NAME]
  ,[ID]
  ,[Gazetteer_]
  ,[Shape_Leng]
  ,[Shape_Le_1]
  ,[Shape_Area]
  ,[ORIG_FID]
  ,dbo.RemoveArtefacts(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromWKB(shape.STUnion(shape.STStartPoint()).STBuffer(0.00001).STBuffer(-0.00001).Reduce(0.000001).STAsBinary(),4326).MakeValid()).MakeValid()   as [Shape]  
INTO
   [MapData].[dbo].[World_SeasSplitGeog]
FROM 
   [MapData].[dbo].[World_SeasSplit]
```

The problem however is that not all the geometries are converted to valid geographies

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided some actual *examples* of the geometries which you're failing to convert.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I wanted to add screenshots as examples but my level does not allow me to add images, the geometries area of all the oceans of the world, thus the WTK is to large to add to the Post, is there a way to attach the shape files to my post?

Comment: not really - are you not able to *simplify* the WTK such that it still causes the issue but isn't so large - doing this can sometimes help you stumble upon the actual problem yourself and either help you solve this yourself or at least better highlight what you believe is causing the problem in your question. And for most questions, people here *prefer* to have the code/text rather than a picture - we can't copy & paste a picture into management studio and start working with it.

Comment: @Meyer: If it's the oceans, and you're on SQL 2008, you're probably running into the issue with the geography type on that version wherein a given geography instance cannot span more than one hemisphere.

Comment: @BenThul We are running SQL 2014. We are not receiving any errors regarding the polygons being more than a hemisphere, the problem is that when looking at the geographies in SOL spatial results certain of the polygons are inverted(Cover the whole world except where they should), where if look at when geometries everything is perfect

Comment: So, the problem is that some of your geometries are specified the wrong way around? *because* the geography type can now cover arbitrary portions of the globe, there has to be an arbitrary rule for deciding whether a ring around the equator is describing the northern hemisphere or the souther hemisphere (this is just an example, the same applies for all shapes). It's the left-hand rule. Reverse the order in which each point is visited for the shapes that don't work correctly currently and it should be fine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever What is the best way then to change the order? I have tried as advised by Spatial Ed's blog to union the start point of the geometry to itself.

Comment: Try ReorientObject. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929311.aspx